# Setting up Devise with gem rails-perftest @Rails 4.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to set up gem rails-perftest with Devise:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'rails/performance_test_help'

class TasksTest < ActionDispatch::PerformanceTest

  include Devise::TestHelpers

  def setup
    # Application requires logged-in user
    david = login(:david)
  end

  test "my_tasks" do
    get '/'
  end
end
```

And I get this error:

```
Error:
TasksTest#test_my_tasks:
NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
```

Where is probably called request.env by Devise::TestHelpers. How to make work sign in with Devise?

Thanks!

David